# Recursion. Find all longest path given a starting point and a maximum distance

Tags: python, recursion

Given a starting point A and a maximum distance D, what are/is the longest path(s) starting from A which have a length superior or equal to D. What is wrong with this piece of code ?

```
def find_paths(graph, start, path, allpaths, dmax):
    if dmax == 0:
        allpaths.append([start])
    else:
        path.append(start)
        for edge in graph[start]:
            d = graph[start][edge]
            if dmax - d >= 0:
                find_paths(graph, edge, path, allpaths, dmax - d)
            else:
                allpaths.append(path)
    return allpaths

graph = { 
          1: {2: 33, 3: 15},
          2: {1: 33, 4: 57, 5: 7},
          3: {1: 15},
          4: {2: 57},
          5: {1: 89, 2: 7},
        }

print find_paths(graph, 1, [], [], 50)
```

This gives:

```
[[1, 2, 5, 2, 3, 1, 3], [1, 2, 5, 2, 3, 1, 3], [1, 2, 5, 2, 3, 1, 3], [1, 2, 5, 2, 3, 1, 3], [1, 2, 5, 2, 3, 1, 3], [1, 2, 5, 2, 3, 1, 3], [1, 2, 5, 2, 3, 1, 3], [1, 2, 5, 2, 3, 1, 3]]
```

The output from `find_paths(graph, 1, [], [], 50)` should be (1, 3) and (1, 2, 5). That is, the two path that go through the vertices 1 and 3 for the first, 1, 2 and 5 for the second one.

Thank you.

Comment: Well, it does output this on my system: [[1, 2, 5, 2, 3, 1, 3], [1, 2, 5, 2, 3, 1, 3], [1, 2, 5, 2, 3, 1, 3], [1, 2, 5, 2, 3, 1, 3], [1, 2, 5, 2, 3, 1, 3], [1, 2, 5, 2, 3, 1, 3], [1, 2, 5, 2, 3, 1, 3], [1, 2, 5, 2, 3, 1, 3]]

Comment: Me too. I'll add it in my post.

Comment: The two paths that go through the vertices (1, 3) and (1, 2 and 5).

Comment: This is the case here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One big problem is that you are appending to path, then passing it to the next iteration of the recursion. That's why you're getting the same result for every path. You need to create a new path each time.

```
def find_paths(graph, start, path, allpaths, dmax):
    if dmax == 0:
        allpaths.append([start])
    else:
        newpath = path + [start]
        for edge in graph[start]:
            d = graph[start][edge]
            if dmax - d >= 0:   
                find_paths(graph, edge, newpath, allpaths, dmax - d)
            else:
                allpaths.append(newpath + [edge])
    return allpaths

graph = { 
          1: {2: 33, 3: 15},
          2: {1: 33, 4: 57, 5: 7},
          3: {1: 15},
          4: {2: 57},
          5: {1: 89, 2: 7},
        }

print find_paths(graph, 1, [], [], 50)
```

Additionally, I'm not sure why you're expecting the result to be (1, 3) and (1, 2, 5). It looks to me like (1, 3) has a length of 15.

Comment: Oh, I'm so silly. I really should have a better look on what I'm doing. But I'm pretty happy that my solution was pretty close to the good one (I'm not that familiar with graphs) !